# Group a sequence of lines [SQL]

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Is there a way to group a sequence of rows in SQL (MySQL 5.1.73).

Let me explain, I have a query that gives this:

| hour | start_date | end_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 2022-02-01 10:11:18 | 2022-02-01 10:50:18 |
| 11 | 2022-02-01 11:30:31 | 2022-02-01 11:38:12 |
| 13 | 2022-02-17 13:55:09 | 2022-02-17 13:58:38 |
| 14 | 2022-02-17 14:51:09 | 2022-02-17 14:57:59 |

And I would like to convert it to this:

| hour | start_date | end_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 2022-02-01 10:11:18 | 2022-02-01 11:38:12 |
| 13 | 2022-02-17 13:55:09 | 2022-02-17 14:57:59 |

Indeed, I would like to group all the lines whose hours follow each other.

My request is a grouping in hours, like this :

```
SELECT hour( date ) as hour, MIN(date) as start_date , MAX(date) as end_date
FROM test_tbl
GROUP BY hour( date ) ,  date( date ) 
order by date, hour( date ) ;
```

But after doing this query, I would like to group the lines whose hours follow each other (10,11 => 10)...

Comment: What's the logic here? Why does hour `10 & 11` in one group and `13 & 14` in another group? How about other hours? Where is hour `12`?

Comment: `I would like to group all the lines whose hours follow each other` maybe you meant `whose days follow each other` ?

Comment: @FanoFN It is a table of traces, with each trace there is a line which is added, sometimes there is no trace for 1 hour.
I would like to group 2 or more lines whose hours follow each other (example: 11, 12, 13 => 11).

Comment: @ErgestBasha no, only the hours...it seems complicated...

Comment: @dev_bi I added an answer please try and let me know, based on your data it seems more like a group on days rather than hours

Comment: What is MySQL version? Please run `SELECT version();` to check

Comment: @FanoFN MYSQL version is 5.1.73

Comment: What if start_date hour is 10 and end_date hour is 11?

Comment: @MeyssamToluie That's exactly what I'm trying to do...

Comment: @dev_bi Explain all exceptions and rules please

Comment: @MeyssamToluie I have to group the lines whose hours follow each other as I said on the initial post. There is no constraint other than that.

Comment: Let's say if the hour is `10,11,12,13,15,16` on the same date, so `10-12` and `15-16`, correct? What will happen to `13`?

Comment: @FanoFN It's more like 10-13 and 15-16 (10,11,12,13 => 10-13)

Comment: Wait, that example was wrong, my bad. I mean, what if there's only a single hour without any immediate hour before or after? Let's say `10,11,12,14,16,17`.. so what will happen to `14`? Will it be shown in the result or not?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: the following answer only works with MySQL version 8+

```
with tbl_by_hour as (
    SELECT hour( date ) as hour, MIN(date) as start_date , MAX(date) as end_date
    FROM test_tbl
    GROUP BY hour( date ) ,  date( date ) 
    order by date, hour( date )
)
select 
    min(hour) as hour, 
    min(start_date) as start_date, 
    max(end_date) as end_date 
    from (
      select tab1.*,
      sum(case when prev_hour is null or prev_hour = hour - 1 then 0 else 1 end) over(order by hour) grp
      from (
        select hour, start_date, end_date, lag(hour) over(order by hour) prev_hour from tbl_by_hour
      ) as tab1
    ) as tab2
group by grp
```

Comment: Thanks, but MySQL doesn't support WITH clause...I should try converting your query to mysql.

Comment: For MYSQL, I created a temporary table instead of the 'with as'. But I have an error on the "over(order by hour) as grp"

Comment: @dev_bi MySQL does support WITH clause from version 8 onwards. Post your query

Comment: @Marko in the comments you have `MySQL version is 5.1.73`

Comment: @dev_bi CTE is supported but column name must be defined before inside query

Comment: @Marko When I just try to do "select hour, start_date, end_date, lag(hour) over(order by hour) prev_hour from tbl_by_hour" I get an error

Comment: @dev_bi please post what's the exact error. Just saying "I get an error" - isn't very useful

Comment: @dev_bi Now I see your version is 5.1.73 which I believe doesn't support window functions (e.g. 'lag'). You need to upgrade the MySQL to at least version 8, otherwise I don't really think this task can be solved with pure queries (i.e. without writing a function/stored procedure)

Comment: @Marko Yes you're right, i get this error : SQL Error (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(order by hour) prev_hour from tbl_by_hour' at line 1

Comment: @Marko Ok thank you very much, I may try to go through Talend

Answer (score 0):

You can probably do something like this:

```
SELECT MIN(hours), dates, MIN(start_date), MAX(end_date), tn
FROM
(SELECT *,
       CEIL(rownum/5) AS tn
 FROM
(SELECT *,
       CASE WHEN dates=@dt
            AND hours=@hr+1
            THEN @rn := @rn+1
            WHEN dates=@dt
            AND hours > @hr+1
            THEN @rn := @rn+20
        ELSE @rn := 1
        END AS rownum,
       @dt := dates,
       @hr := hours
FROM       
 (SELECT hour(date) as hours, date(date) dates, 
        MIN(date) as start_date , MAX(date) as end_date
   FROM test_tbl t 
  GROUP BY dates, hours) v 
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rn := 0, @dt := NULL, @hr := 0) r
ORDER BY dates, hours) s
) w
GROUP BY dates, tn;
```

1. I took your original query as base then made it as subquery.
2. Then I `CROSS JOIN` with a subquery of variables where I'm attempting to generate a custom row numbering. The conditions of the row number are:

- If it's on the same date and the next hour increment from previous is `+1` then continue the numbering.
- If it's on the same date and the next hour increment from previous more than `+1` then pick-up the last number and increment it by `+20`.
- Repeat the row numbering sequence if the date is different.

3. After generating the row numbering, I convert to subquery then divide the row numbering by 5 and use ceiling (`CIEL`) function to somehow make them the same, effectively identifying (assuming) these rows with same `CIEL(rownum/5)` result as one group - this is where I felt it's not really convincing but it works anyhow.
4. Lastly, I convert that to a subquery again and did the whole `MIN(hours), dates, MIN(start_date), MAX(end_date), tn` with `GROUP BY dates, tn`.

It's not a convincing solution because the final operation (generating of the `tn` column) is based on creativity and not something certain. I usually prefer a solution that covers all the possible scenarios with something concrete rather than creative. However, I did some extensive tests on the current query with more data variation and so far it's returning good results. Also, I do notice that you said your MySQL version is 5.1+ so, I'm not really sure if this particular operation will work. Version 5.5+ is probably the lowest version of MySQL fiddle that is available online.

[Here's a demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=16ce47ca7a6f3ccb0fa721fb81fe665a)